# Creating training data from individual .npy files

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I am trying to create training data for my NN project. I have 3 channels I want as input data, representing different spatial fields: `Ux`, `Uy`, and `Uz`. Currently, I've formatted the data as follows:

`Ux`, `Uy`, and `Uz` are all their own folders with ~300-400 `.npy` files depending on the *case*. I have 8 different cases, so my total data size is ~3000. Each numpy array is of size 100x60

```
case_1 >
  Ux >
    Ux_1.npy
    ...
    Ux_350.npy 
  Uy >
    Uy_1.npy
    ...
    Uy_350.npy
  Uz >
    Uz_1.npy 
    ...
    Uz_350.npy

case_2 >
  Ux >
    Ux_1.npy
    ...
    Ux_330.npy 
  Uy >
    Uy_1.npy 
    ...
    Uy_330.npy
  Uz >
    Uz_1.npy
    ...
    Uz_330.npy

....
```

I want my NN input data to have 3 channels as follows:

```
[[Ux_1, Uy_1, Uz_1], .. [Ux_350, Uy_350, Uz_350]]
```

for all 8 cases, so basically a shape of (3000, (3, 100, 60)). The cases do not have to be distinguished, they're all part of the same training data. I would love some guidance on how to start doing this. I am used to already-prepared datasets, and I'm not sure how to combine all `.npy` files into one large tensor for training.

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to construct - on startup - a single tensor containing the 3000 3-layered maps. My recommendation is that you implement your own [Dataset class](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html#dataset-class). This is quite easy and will allow you to control the way your data is manipulated. As well as that you will fetch the `.npy` on demand. This is nice in case your dataset grows.

The essential part is that you're able to map a unique integer to a unique `(Ux_i, Uy_i, Uz_i)` triplet. The tricky part here is that your '`i`s' are spread out in *8* different *case* directories. So that has to be planned out.

Given integer `index`, we need to figure out which case it belongs to. To do so we can use a cumulative array of the case sizes. We'll iterate through it to find the right *case* and then calculate the position of the field in that particular *case*.

Here's how I would implement it:

```
class FieldDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.cases = os.listdir(self.root)

        case_sizes = map(lambda case: self.case_size(case), self.cases)
        self.cum_sizes = np.cumsum(case_sizes)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        for case_i, cum_size in enumerate(self.cum_sizes):
            if index < cum_size:
                break # will leave the loop when index is between cum_sizes[case_i-1] and cum_size
        
        case = self.cases[case_i]
        index -= self.cum_sizes[case_i - 1] # substract sum of all previous cases 
                                            # to get the index in the case of interest 

        fields = []
        for axis in ('x', 'y', 'z'):
            filename = os.sep.join((self.root, case, 'U%s' % axis, 'U%s_%i' % (axis, index))
            layer = np.load(filename)
            fields.append(layer)

        return np.stack(fields, axis=0).

    def case_size(self, case):
        return len(os.listdir((self.root, case, 'Ux'))) # Using the 1st subdirectory 'Ux' to count

    def __len__(self):
        return self.cum_sizes[-1] # last element will be the sum of all case sizes
```

This is just to give you an idea, you can then adapt to your needs or create your very own!